# How can I write a caching HTTP proxy in Perl?

Tags: perl, http, caching, proxy

I intend to write a simple HTTP proxy in Perl using the [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Proxy) module.
I'm clear with the very basic task of how to create a proxy and basic filters and stuff. But what I cannot understand is how to manually force-serve a file through cache.

Basically, the scenario is this that I run this proxy in computer A. The user on computer B accesses web uses this proxy. Now, this proxy will just act as a pass through for all B's requests, until he requests a particular URL (a file, say http://abc.com/file.zip). I need to intercept this request, and instead of allowing him to download the actual file.zip, give him an already downloaded file that I manually kept on computer A.

Also, note that I might not have a web server running on computer A, so I can't just redirect the url, I need to serve it from cache.

Any pointers for this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Edit: Some more info. I started using HTTP::Daemon and LWP::UserAgent in combination instead of HTTP::Proxy
So far, I intercept all requests successfully, and then I search the headers for the url. If the particular filename is not there, I just pass the request to actual destination using LWP:UserAgent (simple_request) and return the response to original sender using send_response. If I find the filename, I don't further forward the request, instead I'm trying to serve my particular file using "send_file_response" method. The problem is that all other requests  are working fine and comp B is able to surf the net, but when it tries to download this file, it just keeps waiting for a response.
About using squid, It is not an option for me to install squid on these machines.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be better to just use [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) for something like this?

Comment: yeah, it would be easier to use squid, but I can't because I'm not allowed to install anything on the machines in question.

Answer (score 1):

I think from the distance, we can only guess as to while the send_file_response is not working.
I'd recommend

- read and understand the documentation for the modules and methods you are using
- log the action somehow in the proxy server (start, end)
- trace the communication between client B and proxy server.

Comment: Thnx Ingo..The problem is that the documentation for this module, especially this method is pretty sparse. I'm trying to log things and check it out that way. Will post with more info here soon.

Comment: You may also want to look at the perl source if documentation is lacking.